# Executing a simple powershell command on the command line

Tags: windows, powershell

I try to run a simple powershell command by setting a variable and printing it.

This is what I want to do:

```
powershell -command "& {$name=\"hi\"; echo $name}"
```

But it fails with:

```
The string is missing the terminator: ".
   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

The invoke operator (`&`) works fine with *commands* such as:

```
 powershell -command "& {&echo hi}"
```

I read about the invoking operator and how to execute commands with `-command` option and executing scripts with `-File` option etc. They are working as expected. But my attempts to do the same for setting a variable and printing it as above doesn't work. I suspect `-command` works with only *commands*. Any idea how to achieve what I do above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from a DOS shell this works:

```
powershell -command "& {$name='hi'; echo $name}"
```

but also your code works.

From a Powershell console use this:

```
powershell -command {$name='hi'; echo $name}
```

Comment: My bad! My actual command is bit more complicated. What I posted was a simplified example. I had the invoking operator inside the command block which caused the problem. Thanks for the help!